# GLib-GObject-WARNING: Core dump when running Inkscape on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, glib, inkscape

On two different computers, Inkscape sometimes crashes with the following error messages:

```
(inkscape:2536): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type `(null)' in cast to `GtkBin'
(inkscape:2536): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type `(null)' in cast to `GtkBin'
(inkscape:2536): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from `GtkLabel' to `GtkBin'
[...]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I googled the error messages but could not find any satisfying answers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, you can do anything about it, except by filing a bug report here: https://code.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/trunk, specifying your version of inkscape and platform. Things like that happen from time to time with Gtk+.

I believe, in this case some inkscape programmer has forgotten to make some validity check before variable assignment. Don't get why a GtkLabel would be assigned to GtkBin, Label isn't a Bin in Gtk+.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll file the bug report and we'll see whether they fix it or not

Comment: Happy New Year (hope, Inkscape gets friendlier in 2014, cause now I'm bit of a hater :)